# Which long-standing open problems follow immediately from the proof of the abc conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory

Some blogs/articles claim that many problems will follow immediately from the ABC theorem if it is indeed a theorem. For example Fermat's last theorem will follow in a one-page proof from the abc theorem.

My question is: can someone use the abc theorem to outline some proofs of open problems, or solved problems with difficult proofs, that are solved immediately using the abc theorem? It would be best if there is one solved proof per answer.

I am also especially interested in seeing a one-page proof of Fermat's last theorem using the ABC theorem!

Comment: You might start by reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture#Some_consequences

Comment: Another site: http://www.math.unicaen.fr/~nitaj/abc.html#Consequences

Comment: As far as I know, there is no one page proof of full FLT. However: Suppose $x^n + y^n = z^n$ and assume the solution is coprime and nontrivial, which is no real restriction, then by ABC each of $x^n, y^n, z^n$ is bounded by $C_{\varepsilon} (xyz)^{1 + \varepsilon}$ so that $x^n y^n z^n \le C_{\varepsilon}^3 (xyz)^{3 + 3 \varepsilon}$, which shows that for $n$ large enough there are no solutions and for $n\ge 4$ there are at most finitely many.

Comment: @quid: so I guess in a similar vein, one can also make conditional statements for twin primes? (sorry, vague thought)

Comment: It seems also worthwhile to note when considering consequences that just vaguely 'ABC conjecture' can be problematic as there are various forms. It would seem good to be a bit more *precise* regarding what is to be assumed proven. To document that this is not some bogus-request and to possibly help in doing I refer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/106321/mochizukis-proof-and-siegel-zeros . 

Comment: @Suvrit: sorry I do not follow: twinprime would yiels, say p + 2 = q , but then p,q,2 are all prime so that the restriction one gets from ABC is that each of them is less that C (2pq)^{1+eps} which is, well, not much of a restriction :) But perhaps you meant something else.  

Comment: Assuming ABC, one can prove that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $2^{p-1}\not\equiv1\pmod{p^2}$. The proof isn't particularly hard, but not completely trivial. Of course, we expect most primes to have this property, but even the weaker statement has eluded unconditional proof. The fact that ABC implies this is in J. Number Theory 30 (1988), 226-237.

Comment: A general reference that is perhaps of interest to get a flavor of variations of ABC and equivalent formulations, a proof like the one I gave above for a more general type of equation, and some other results without proof (including Joe Silverman's) is this paper by Goldfeld http://www.math.columbia.edu/~goldfeld/ABC-Conjecture.pdf

Comment: @quid: no, I wanted to see if the restriction that one gets from abc makes any difference [and since I obviously don't understand what is going on, I asked that dumb question :-) ]

Comment: This is discussed in Lang, Serge
Old and new conjectured Diophantine inequalities. 
Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.) 23 (1990), no. 1, 37–75. 

Comment: Here is a survey article by Andrew Granville and Tom Tucker: http://www.ams.org/notices/200210/fea-granville.pdf