# Does Mochizuki's proof of abc conjecture gives an upper bound for the quality of a triple?

Tags: nt.number-theory, abc-conjecture

The quality of a triple $(a,b,c)$  of coprime positive integers with $a + b = c$ is defined as
$$q(a,b,c) := \frac{\log(c)}{\log(\mathrm{rad}(abc))}.$$ 
Then
$$a+b = c = \mathrm{rad}(abc)^{q(a,b,c)}.$$
The triple with the highest known quality is $(2, 3^{10} \cdot 109, 23^5)$, with $q(a,b,c) = 1.6299...$
If the abc conjecture is true then the quality of any triple is bounded (expected by $2$).

Assuming Mochizuki's proof correct, does it gives an explicit upper bound for the quality of a triple?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://mathoverflow.net/a/106399

Comment: The role of (many!) Belyi maps in the proof (if correct...) is probably a substantial obstacle to extracting any explicit numerical bounds for theoretical situations.

Comment: The answer is no, according to Mochizuki.